# npg sudden error installing things

Tags: npm

When I try to install `npm install _____` I get this weird error I've never seen before. I opened powershell as admin and tried there, but got the same error. Also tried installing in safe mode, turning off many programs, npm cache clean --force, deleting and re-installing npm, cmd as admin, and many other things...
It was working fine last night, but when I woke up it stopped working....

```
PS Z:\myapp> npm install @google/maps
npm ERR! path Z:\myapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev\package.json
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'Z:\myapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev\package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'Z:\myapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev\package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'Z:\\myapp\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\abbrev\\package.json\'\n    at Error (native)',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'Z:\\myapp\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\abbrev\\package.json' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-09-12T13_11_39_774Z-debug.log
```

It freezes at `postinstall: info lifecycle @types/googlemaps@3.26.20~postinstall: @types/googlemaps@3.26.20` then eventually just crashes totally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **--no-optional** while installing any package.
`npm install nodemon --no-optional`

Comment: That installed it.... but this is happening with all the packages and it just started today when I woke up... the first thing I did tho was update npm to the most recent version. That's probably what did it. Do you know why this worked? I'm not sure I understand, and I'd rather not have to force everything going forward

Comment: Also, what's nodemon? Do I need that for something?

Comment: nodemon is nothing, just an example I took. like installing any package say nodemon.